# getting values inserted into mysql and setting a value from '0' to '1'?

Tags: php, mysql

i need some help with my block user script. i am trying to get it to insert the values and then set the column blocked from '0' to '1'.

It inserts the values fine, by which i mean it inserts the user_id and blocked_id without a prbolem, but it's causing me syntax errors when i try and get it to set blocked from '0' to '1'.

Can anyone show me where im going wrong, thanks.

CODE:

```
<?php

require_once('includes/session.php');
require_once('includes/functions.php');
require('includes/_config/connection.php');

session_start();

    confirm_logged_in();

    if (isset ($_GET['to'])) {
    $user_to_id = $_GET['to'];


}


if (!isset($_GET['to']))
    exit('No user specified.');

$user_id = $_GET['to'];




$result1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ptb_block_user (user_id, blocked_id) VALUES (".$_SESSION['user_id'].", ".$user_to_id.")")

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT ptb_block_user SET blocked='1' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."") 


or $result3 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM ptb_block_user WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND blocked_id = ".$user_to_id.""); header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");



if($result1) 
{ 
$_SESSION['message2']="<div class=\"infobox-profile\"><strong>User Blocked</strong> - This user has successfully been blocked. You will no longer be abler to interact with each other's profiles.</div><div class=\"infobox-close\"></div>"; 
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
} 
else 
if($result3) 
{ 
$_SESSION['message2']="<div class=\"infobox-favourites\"><strong>User Unblocked</strong> - This user has successfully been unblocked. You can now interact with each other's profiles.</div><div class=\"infobox-close4\"></div>"; 
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");

}
?>
```

Comment: I see no code incrementing from `0` to `1`, however I do see code that looks very susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: the table field may have a default of 0 and he is trying to update the field to 1. but used a select instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
$result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_block_user SET blocked='1' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."")
```

Use "update", not "select" to alter a row.